# parameterized insert query not working

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

I am trying to run what I thought was a rather simple parameterized insert query, but am running into all sorts of problems. SQL EXPRESS 08R2, VB.net

Here is the VB code that builds the parameters...
UPDATED Variable names:

```
itemDataSource1.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ToString()
itemDataSource1.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
itemDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@short_Text", short_Text) 
itemDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@foreignTable", foreignTable)
itemDataSource1.InsertCommand = "usp_insertLangShortText"         ' Call stored procedure

'***********************************************************************
 ' Begin the insertion. Check for errors during insert process.

Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0
rowsAffected = itemDataSource1.Insert()
```

And here is the SP that I am trying to perform the insert with..

```
@short_Text varchar(250), 
@foreignTable varchar(250)

AS
/* SET NOCOUNT ON */
DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

   BEGIN
SET @sql =  'INSERT INTO ' + @foreignTable + ' (short_Text) VALUES (''' + @short_Text + ''')';
   END

print (@sql) 
EXECUTE(@sql); 
SET @sql = '' 

RETURN
```

ANY suggestions on how to code this more intelligently are welcome.

Here is the error....
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function usp_insertLangShortText has too many arguments specified. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.Insert() at par_importExcelDataPTS.GetRootID(String short_Text, Int32 string_id, String dbName, String Lang_code) in C:\Users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you may need to add an @ in front of the parameter names when you add them:

```
itemDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@short_Text", short_Text) 
itemDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@foreignTable", foreignTable)
```

Also, if your short_text contains any single quotes, the SQL will fail to evaluate. To resolve this, replace all single quotes in short_Text with two single quotes.

If this does not resolve your issue, can you post the exact error messages that you are receiving?

Comment: apostrophes have all been escaped, the text strings do not have apostrophes that are not updating. I'll try changing the @ signs.

Comment: Ah, the exception helps: for some reason your parameter isn't making it. I have two ideas about why this might be: 1) The parameters are getting cleared when you set InsertCommand; try moving it above the area where the parameters are set; 2) short_text is Nothing; step into the code in debug and make sure that this value is set.

Comment: Stepped into the code short_text is getting set just fine. I will try moving the InsertCommand. As a note, when I execute the line, rowsAffected = itemDataSource1.Insert() , the parameters are set as well.

Comment: It looks like your error message may have changed: the error is that there are too many parameters. Can you check the number of parameters just before the call to insert (it could be that the parameters are already added; you may need to clear the parameters collection before adding the new ones or they may be added automatically). If there are only 2 parameters, then the issue is with your stored procedure definition (i.e. it no no longer has 2 parameters). If the parameters are auto-added by .Net, you may have 3 parameters, the first of which will be the return value from the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific reason the parameter names are different as this may be causing your issue:

c# - `itemDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("short_Text", short_Text)`

SQL - `@shrtText varchar(250)`

Should it not be: `itemDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("shrtText", short_Text)`

Comment: No that did not fix the issue.

Comment: Can you try `itemDataSource1.InsertParameters["short_Text"].DefaultValue = short_Text` for both params instead of the .add method